# Configure recovery methods for windows service via Visual Studio Deployment project.

Tags: windows-services, installation, setup-deployment

I have created an installer with Visual Studio Deployment project to install a windows service. I need to add more feature like:
1] Recovery methods like, Restart the service on first failure, restart the service on second failure.
2] Stop the service before the installer tries to upgrade to next version.

Any pointers or any resources for this task is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6164/A-ServiceInstaller-Extension-That-Enables-Recovery) helpful? This article demonstrates how you can extend the ServiceInstaller class to enable the configuration of the recovery options in your program code instead of having to reset it in the Services Manager window each time you reinstall.